# Regular expression pattern that ignores double appearance of a character

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Looking for a regular expression pattern that detect a single character (specific) , but ignores it when comes in double or triple... N.

```
abcde <- looking for this (c's separated by another character)
abccdce <- not this (immediately repeating c's)
```

I'd like to replace single characters but ignore them when repeating.

Desired results (replace single 'c' with 'FOO')

```
abcde -> abFOOde
abccdce -> abccdce
abcdeabccde ->abFOOdeabccde
```

Hint: I know how to do the opposite - replace double but ignore singles

```
$pattern = '/c\1{1}/x';
$replacement = 'FOO';
preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

Comment: Why "abccdce" doesn't produce "abccdFOOe"? As an aside writting `{1}` in a regex pattern is always useless.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
(?<!c)c(?!c)
```

Which means match `c` if not surrounded by `c`s on either side.

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(?<!c)  # negative lookbehind to fail the match if previous position as c
c       # match literal c
(?!c)   # negative lookahead to fail the match if next position as c
```

**Code:**

```
$repl = preg_replace('/(?<!c)c(?!c)/', 'FOO', $text);
```